# Odd Jersey Error: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

We have seen this multiple times and it does not seem to be related to our code as none of our code is in the stacktrace.  We are using Jersey 1.17 and we get, occasionally, this error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   java.lang.String.toLowerCase(String.java:2496)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.util.StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.hash(StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.java:53)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.util.StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.hash(StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.java:48)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.util.KeyComparatorHashMap.keyComparatorHash(KeyComparatorHashMap.java:294)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.util.KeyComparatorHashMap.containsKey(KeyComparatorHashMap.java:359)  at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:101) at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:104) at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:104) at ...

And then the last line repeats forever (well, until a stackoverflow).  We saw this more in 1.18 and so we downgraded to 1.17 but now I just saw it there.

These webservices work 99.9% of the time.  This causes trouble in the jvm.  Anyone else seen this?  What am I doing wrong?  We just have a normal 1.17 install and the entire app is built around it.

Update:  Since someone suggested a loop in the app server, we are using Tomcat 6 and basic auth.

Comment: And what is the code at `HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:104`?

Comment: you're trying to auth, with a kind of loop. Sometimes Auth filters loop on them, you need to stop them in case of error. 1. calling auth by client, 2. auth call in app 3. service needs Auth, 4. Auth Call .... this can easily make a loop

Comment: We do not do auth in the app that I know of (we do use tomcat and it does the basic auth).  Also, if you notice above the rest of the enormous stack trace is at line 104.  So the first one is 101 and the rest are at 104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a buddy of mine found this and I can't believe my own stupidity.

```
this.theBasicAuthClient.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(logon, password));
```

I was adding this on EVERY invocation.  So we make the client in the constructor of our class and reuse it.  In passing I thought this just added the basic auth credentials in the header of the request but it really adds another filter.  So everytime we executed this client call we added another filter!  GAA!

Just add it when you create the client and move on...